# flutter : how do i create a text widget with link and clickable icon

Tags: flutter

How do I create the picture below in flutter.  I tried using Richtext and widget span (clickable icon) but getting an error with widget span.. Is there another method to do this with a different layout without widgetspan

here my code

```
Expanded(
          child: RichText(
            text: new TextSpan(
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text:
                      'Email me career-related  updates and job opportunities. company  ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Palette.DARK_BLUE, fontSize: 16.0),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'privacy policy',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Palette.DARK_BLUE,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                      launch('https://www.google.com');
                    },
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: ' and ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Palette.DARK_BLUE, fontSize: 16.0),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'terms of use ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Palette.DARK_BLUE,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                      launch('https://www.google.com/');
                    },
                ),
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.info_outline,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked perfectly. the only error I got, was because of the `Expanded`  widget. after removing the expanded widget, I didn't get any errors.

Comment: @aligator , thanks .. when I scroll up or down .,. I get the error "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
". if I remove the "WidgetSpan" then the error goes away

Comment: I tried it again and I'm not getting this or any other error.